# Spring CrudRepository query with child element?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

i have couchbase document like following

```
{
  "contentTimestamp": 1470216079085,
  "version": 12,
  "content": [
    {
      "text": "ABC",
      "params": {
        "TYPE": "TEXT"
      }
    }
    ],
  "readers": {
    "u_id_1": 0,
    "u_id_2": 0,
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "id": "u_id_1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Document class

```
@Document
public class ContentDoc implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private Integer version = 12;

    @Field
    private List<Content> content = new ArrayList<>();

    @Field
    private Map<String, Object> readers = new HashMap<>();

    //etc

    //getter setter

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public interface ContentDocRepository extends CrudRepository<ContentDoc, String> {

    public List<ContentDoc> findByReadersIn(String reader) throws Exception;

}
```

Testcase

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Tests {

    @Autowired
    private ContentDocRepository contentDocRepository;

    @Test
    public void cotentDocRepoTest(){

        List<ContentDoc> contents = contentDocRepository.findByReadersIn("u_id_1");
        Assert.assertNotNull(contents);
        System.out.println(contents)
    }
}
```

I wrote code as per above but not able to retrieve result always got empty arraylist.

Anyone knows what going wrong with my code and how can i execute query with child element?

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long RND and experiment i got solution,

> we dont have way to finding child element with method name so we need
> to do as per my following answer

Steps :

1. Create custom view in couchbase as per following

*viewname* : findContentByUser

```
function (doc, meta) {
  
  if(doc._class == "package.model.ContentDoc") {
    for(var i=0; i < doc.contributors.length; i++){
         emit(doc.contributors[i].id, null);
    }
       
  }
}
```

2. *Repository* : binding viewname and designDocument with impl method as per following

   ```
    @Repository
    public interface ContentDocRepository extends CrudRepository<ContentDoc, String> {

       @View(viewName = "findContentByUser", designDocument="dev_content")
       public List<ContentDoc> findByContributors_id(String id);   
   }
   ```

Finally Got result :)

Comment: Thanks , its very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a view anymore, just use the @N1qlPrimaryIndexed and @ViewIndexed annotations and it should work out-of-the-box:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "building")
public interface BuildingRepository extends 
CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Building, String> {

    List<Building> findByCompanyId(String companyId);

}
```

I answered a very similar question here [Using IN clause in couchbase N1Ql @query or use findAll(keys) from couchbase JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449420/using-in-clause-in-couchbase-n1ql-query-or-use-findallkeys-from-couchbase-jpa/49452044#49452044)

And you can follow my tutorial here:
https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/

Comment: The question was related to fetch parent on top child elements filter.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Service
public interface ContentDocRepository extends CrudRepository<ContentDoc, String> {

    @View(viewName = "findContentByUser", designDocument="dev_content")
    public List<ContentDoc> findByContributors_id(String id) throws Exception;

}
```

Comment: Please explain the code and place better the markdown "code"

Comment: it's already explain above I don't know why you have repeated.