# Having trouble with Couchbase view filtering

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using spring-data-couchbase, and I'm trying to create a backing view for a `findAll()` query. I've created a document named `ClusterCodeXref`, and a view named `allClusterCodeXrefs` matching my model class. I need to filter the based on the calling class (did I state that right?), because this bucket will be used for other applications too.

My model looks like this:

```
package com.company.aad.xref.model;

@Document
public class ClusterCodeXref implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3072475211055736282L;

    @Id
    String id;

    @Field("SET_NUM")
    String setNum;

    ...
}
```

This is the repository class:

```
@Repository

public interface ClusterCodeXrefRepository
  extends CrudRepository<ClusterCodeXref, String> {

    @View
    List<ClusterCodeXref> findAllClusterCodeXrefs();
}
```

And this is my view:

```
function (doc, meta) {  
  if (doc._class == "com.company.aad.xref.model.ClusterCodeXref") {
    emit(meta.id, null);
  }
}
```

But when I run the `findAllClusterCodeXrefs()` query, no rows are returned. If I take the if-statement out, I get everything I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `_class` field isn't automatically added to imported data. I need to add `_class` to my dataset (which I imported from a CSV file) manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify via annotations to automatically generate a view and a primary index for this document, as follows:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "clusterCodeXref")
@Repository

public interface ClusterCodeXrefRepository extends CrudRepository<ClusterCodeXref, String> {

    @View
    List<ClusterCodeXref> findAllClusterCodeXrefs();
}
```

I answered a very similar question here  [Spring CrudRepository query with child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758878/spring-crudrepository-query-with-child-element/49678089#49678089)

Comment: Thank you! But what would the index look like??

Comment: I need to tell another team how to look up the data, and I don’t know that they’ll be using Spring.

Comment: You can also specify the view name using   @View(designDocument = "user", viewName = "byName") check out  http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/